# javascript + opacity transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I want to be able to change the opacity of a div by clicking on it. I wrote the following code but it looks like the `opacity: 1s` doesn't work , any idea why ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        div {
            background-color: red;
            opacity: 0.1;
            filter: Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE8 and earlier */,
            transition: opacity 1s;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function changeOpacity() {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity = 1;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id ="myDiv"onclick="changeOpacity()">
        This element's opacity is 0.5! Note that both the text and the background-color are affected by the opacity level!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `,` after `filter`? Is it correctly?

Comment: @stachu : omg , what a mistake. thanks

Comment: no problem, small mistakes is hard to fix :D

Comment: I think Alpha it should be just alpha. http://output.jsbin.com/pumesayiru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope to help, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    div {
        background-color: red;
        opacity: 0.1;
        filter: Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE8 and earlier */,
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id ="myDiv"onclick="changeOpacity()">This element's opacity is 0.5! Note that both the text and the background-color are affected by the opacity level!</div>
<script>
    function changeOpacity(){
       document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity = 1;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```